# Leptonica cropping image on rotation

Tags: rotation, crop, leptonica

```
PIX* returnRotatedImage(PIX* image, float theta)
{
    PIX* rotated = pixRotate(image, -theta, L_ROTATE_AREA_MAP, L_BRING_IN_BLACK, image->w, image->h);

    return rotated;
}
```

When I execute the above code on an image, the resulting image has the edges cut off.

Example: the original scan, followed by the image after being run through the above function to rotate it by ~89 degrees.

I don't have 10 reputation yet, so I can't embed the images, but here's a link to the two pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHoLS.jpg

I need it to work for arbitrary angles as well (not just angles close to 90 degrees), so unfortunately the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572994/image-pixels-getting-lost-while-rotation-using-leptonica) won't work.

The description for the pixRotate function says:

```
 *      (6) The dest can be expanded so that no image pixels
 *          are lost.  To invoke expansion, input the original
 *          width and height.  For repeated rotation, use of the
 *          original width and height allows the expansion to
 *          stop at the maximum required size, which is a square 
 *          with side = sqrt(w*w + h*h).
```

however it seems to be expanding the destination after rotation, and thus the pixels are lost, even if the final image size is correct.  If I use pixRotate(..., 0, 0) instead of pixRotate(..., w, h), I end up with the image rotated within the original dimensions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZtq.jpg.

Am I interpreting the pixRotate function description incorrectly?  Is what I want to do even possible?  Or is this possibly a bug?

Thanks in advance.